# Stack Overflow Relationship... What am I?

Tags: riddle

I am the reason you are here
The salvation of the digital world

I am quite simple 
as I am quite hyper at first

Yet I can sit 
And create speeches and essays for everyone

I can fly like the wind 
No restrictions from gravity 
And a good mark in my criminal record

You speak of me 
By mouth or text, who knows what's next?

> Who am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are :

> HTML

I am the reason you are here The salvation of the digital world

> HTML is the way the website works, and quite literally sustains the digital world i.e. the internet

I am quite simple as I am quite hyper at first

> HTML is a relatively simple language, since it's hyper(text markup).

Yet I can sit And create speeches and essays for everyone

> "Text" is what written speeches and essays are written in.

I can fly like the wind No restrictions from gravity And a good mark in my criminal record

> "Mark- up!"HTML can move as quickly as the speed of your internet connection.

You speak of me By mouth or text

> "Language" is used by mouth and text - orally and written. We speak and write about HTML constantly on StackOverflow

Who knows what's next?

> The future of computing is unknown. Who knows what the next creative use of HTML will be?

Comment: Imagine each clue telling you one of the four words in your answer. "I am quite hyper at first" is pretty blatant, yes? Now look at the second word, take the clue as applying not to your whole answer but to that word. Agree? Then the third and fourth clues will be much easier...

Comment: I'll give the accept due to the answer is right but you might want to fix your reasoning a bit

Answer (score 5):

I think you are :

> Reputation

I am the reason you are here
The salvation of the digital world

> We are here for sharing our knowledge and gain reputation.

I am quite simple
as I am quite hyper at first

> At first, it is hard to gain reputation but after a while it becomes easier

Yet I can sit
And create speeches and essays for everyone

> Reputation details give all the information about us, badges and achievements are the reference for speeches and essays.

I can fly like the wind
No restrictions from gravity
And a good mark in my criminal record

> Reputation has no limits, you can go higher and earn everyday. And while gaining it, your record becomes better as well.

You speak of me
By mouth or text, who knows what's next?

> This I can't directly relate but, may be unlocking more privilages by gaining reputation